# Save scene to camera roll

Tags: ios, iphone, vuforia

I'm working on augmented reality app for iPhone and I'm using sample code "ImageTargets" from Vuforia SDK. I'm using my own images as templates and my own model to augment the scene (just a few vertices in OpenGL). Next thing I wanna do is to save the scene to camera roll after pushing a button. I created the button as well as the method the button responds to. Here comes the tricky part. When I press the button the method gets called, image is properly saved, but the image is completely white showing only the button icon (like this http://tinypic.com/r/16c2kjq/5).

```
- (void)saveImage {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.layer.frame.size);
  [self.view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self,
    @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (void)image: (UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error 
  contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {
   NSLog(@"Image Saved");
}
```

I have these 2 methods in ImageTargetsParentViewController class but I also tried saving the view from ARParentViewController (and even moved the methods to the class). Has anyone found solution to this? I'm not so sure which view to save and/or whether there aren't any tricky parts with saving the view that contains OpeglES. Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code for save photo:

```
- (void)saveImage {

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *imagee = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect rect;
rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imagee CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, Nil, Nil, Nil);
```

Comment: Doing the same thing as before. Is it working for you in Image Targets? Mistery to me :-O

Comment: @dew this work for me.. looking at your code known that the first row is different from mine ..

Comment: From which class do you save the View? I tried ImageTargetsParentViewController which i thought was right, but it still only saves the icon :/

Comment: And which frameworks do you import into the class? I import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: So I managed to get it to work, but it was way harder than I expected. Found this few solutions at vuforia web (https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/vuforia-sdk-how-take-screenshots), so I combined few of them and its somehow working. Thanks for replies